# Cannot create instance of [UserControl] in WPF designer

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls, datatrigger

I've been having some weird issues with the WPF designer, it claims it can't instantiate the user control, even though when I run the program, it works just fine, I've managed to find the piece of code which causes the issue, however I can't exactly understand why.

**After cleaning the solution:**

[image: Everything seems to be fine here]

**Clean & Rebuild:**

[image: The error showed up]

Error message: `Error   1   Cannot locate resource 'userinterface/visualresources/images/error.png'.    C:\Users\......\Armt\Armt\UserInterface\Views\MainWindow.xaml   21  9   Armt`

This is the code it claims to be faulty:

```
                        <GridViewColumn >
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate DataType="models:Issue">
                                <Image x:Name="image" Source="/UserInterface\VisualResources\Images\information.png" Height="14" Width="14" />
                                ******FROM HERE******
                                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Severity}" Value="Error" >
                                        <Setter TargetName="image" Property="Source" Value="/UserInterface\VisualResources\Images\error.png" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Severity}" Value="Warning" >
                                        <Setter TargetName="image" Property="Source" Value="/UserInterface\VisualResources\Images\warning.png" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                ******END******
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
```

Removing the `DataTemplate.Triggers` part makes everything work both in and out of the designer, and if I select the IssuesListView UserControl tab and hit rebuild, the error goes away, only when I change back to the main view tab it comes back again.

This is the UserControl's constructor:

```
    public IssuesListView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // To avoid design-time issues
        if (!System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
        {
            DataContext = ((App)Application.Current).GetInstance<IssuesListViewVm>();
        }
    }
```

What could be happening here? Somehow the designer can't find the resource but at runtime it does?

Comment: Use [Pack URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I've already tried that, the error persists.